# Replacing multiple invalid characters in a sheet name

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am writing a fairly large macro

- which ends by saving the workbook with a name that the user inputted earlier on.
- I am using the title of the sheet for this, so I need to strip out any reserved characters that will throw up file system errors `(/\*|?:<>")`.

I would like to avoid having to use a large number of `Replace()` statements, so is there any way to replace multiple characters with an underscore in one statement - something more like a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp)?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Happily you will find that most of these characters are invalid already as sheet name characters, ie `*?[]` etc

But as you have said already, use a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) :)

Something like below to return `True` for valid strings, `False` for invalid ones.

I have added your items above, escaping special characters as needed.

***[Updated: added replacement Function]***

```
Sub TestCleanNames()
    Dim StrArr()
    Dim StrTst
    StrArr = Array("Am i ok", "Sheet||a", "audited??", "Sheet1")
    For Each StrTst In StrArr
        MsgBox StrTst & " = " & ValidSheetName(CStr(StrTst)) & vbNewLine & CleanSheetName(CStr(StrTst))
    Next
End Sub
```

*valid name function*

```
Function ValidSheetName(strIn As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegex.Pattern = "[\<\>\*\\\/\?|]"
    ValidSheetName = Not objRegex.test(strIn)
End Function
```

*clean function*

```
Function CleanSheetName(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[\<\>\*\\\/\?|]"
        CleanSheetName = .Replace(strIn, "_")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: +1 you wouldn't need to test for backslash, `/`, `*`, or `?` because they are prohibited worksheet name characters.

Comment: I haven't been particularly clear with my wording here - unfortunately the actual sheet name and the name I am referring to are different - my name goes into the header of the sheet! However, brettdj's response is pretty much perfect on this one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [clean()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/clean.php)?

Alternatively, a bit messier, but I believe you could use ['substitute'](http://www.likeoffice.com/28057/excel-string#3)

```
Substitute( text, old_text, new_text, nth_appearance )
```