# Run Time Error - Cannot access file

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA script which saves a workbook and this works fine.

However if commandbutton1 is clicked again it correctly brings up the option box

> 'Do you want to replace the file'- Yes, No, Cancel.

The yes option works fine but the No and Cancel option bring up an error box - `RunTime error 1004: Cannot access 'file'`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve the problem please. Code is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String
Path = "C:\temp\Saved Invoices\"
FileName1 = Range("R12")
FileName2 = Range("S12")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName1 & "-" & FileName2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52 
End Sub
```

Comment: Given you are using cell contents for filenames, suggest you check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/8591088/641067 (code that will check and remove any invalid characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would still like a prompt for your user, you can do so using a MsgBox.  Below is a simple Yes/No prompt.

This code uses the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  If you don't already have this referenced, go to the Visual Basic Editor (ALT-F11) and in the Tools dropdown, select "References..."  Tick the check-box next to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and then click the OK button.

The code below sets up the FileSystemObject, sets the path and filename you provided, and checks if that file already exists.  If it doesn't find the file, it will SaveAs like before.  If it already finds the file, it will give the user a MsgBox asking whether they'd like to overwrite the file or not.  If they click YES, it does a SaveAs like before.  Clicking NO will do nothing.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName1 As String
    Dim FileName2 As String
    Dim FilePath As String

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Path = "C:\temp\Saved Invoices\"
FileName1 = Range("R12")
FileName2 = Range("S12")
FilePath = Path & FileName1 & "-" & FileName2 & ".xlsm"

If fso.FileExists(FilePath) Then
    If MsgBox("Your file already exists in this location.  Do you want to replace it?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FilePath, 52
    End If
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FilePath, 52
End If

End Sub
```

Application.DisplayAlerts provided by Thinkingcap is also a great method.  The reason you received the error in the first place is because your script knew what to do when they clicked YES but had no direction for NO or CANCEL.  When prompts are enabled, NO is the selected default for SaveAs.  Wrapping your script in Application.DisplayAlerts = False not only disables prompts but changes the default value to YES, so it replaces the file every time without user input.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you. This works great and does exactly what I was trying to achieve. Particular thanks, from a newcomer to VBA, for the explanations. It gives me a great starting point next time in my thought trains. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to wrap the code in  [Application.DisplayAlerts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782(v=office.15).aspx)

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Dim Path As String
 Dim FileName1 As String
 Dim FileName2 As String
 Path = "C:\temp\Saved Invoices\"
 FileName1 = Range("R12")
 FileName2 = Range("S12")
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName1 & "-" & FileName2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer - it works fine now. I'm new to vba and trying to understand it so can I ask if it's possible to code the script so that it does warn if by clicking commandbutton1 for a second time it brings up the overwrite warning.

Comment: The way the question was framed and the comfort level of the OP , I figured this solution was simple , I m sure there are more ways to solve this!