# How do I create a macro in excel that will save the current document to a specific location

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a template in excel 2010 and I want to make a macro that will save the current document to a folder with the name of a specific cell.

How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There's quite a few tutorials available online for this sort of macro.

Comment: See [`Saveas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827292/run-time-error-cannot-access-file/24827548#24827548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say cell **D8** in *Sheet4* contains:

C:\TestFolder

The try something like:

```
Sub SaveMe()
    s1 = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("D8").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs s1 & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Based on your comments the modified code should be:

```
Sub SaveMe()
    s1 = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("D8").Value
    patth = "P:\2013\processed\" & s1 & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs patth
End Sub
```

Comment: awesome this is really helpful. Specifically, I have a serial number in one of the cells and that serial number has a folder on my hard drive, and I want to save the excel document in that folder. Do you know how that would change the code? I'm very unfarmiliar with vba sorry

Comment: Update your original post to indicate **both** a sample cell contents and corresponding folder.

Comment: sample cell content: CF13G16
sample corresponding folder: P:\2013\processed\CF13G16

Comment: Okay great. It's giving me an error code 1004 now however. It said Method "SaveAs" of object "_Workbook" failed

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the developer tab and record a macro.  Then do a save as to whatever location you want... Then stop recording the macro and view the code. should look like this.

x = the cell you want

```
ChDir "path"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "path" & x ".xls", _
    FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```