# Excel date change VBA Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a macro that will change the name of the current sheet open in Excel.

Its taking the information from a cell that contains a date in the future however cause the format of the date is dd/mm/yyyy it wont import it. I'M trying to get it to display it as 11th August 2011 or something like that. This is what i have got so far and I can't seem to find anything on the web.

```
Sub ChangeSheetName()

newname = Range("D2")

ActiveSheet.Name = newname

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `newname = Range("D2").Text` to get the date.

Editted:
Do take note that the date format in the cell need to be changed
[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work, as `Range.Text` will look like "01/01/2015" which is not a valid sheet name (because of the slashes).

Comment: The cells format need to be changed, else it will pop out error message box.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the forward slashes in the date.  You can either use `Format()` to re-format the date into something that doesn't contain slashes - e.g.

```
If IsDate(Range("A1").Value) Then
    newname = Format(Range("A1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
Else
    'Handle the error here
End If
```

This doesn't rely on the cell being in the correct format.  Note also that if `D2` doesn't contain a date, then `Format` would just leave it alone - possibly including invalid characters - hence why I check first.

A more general solution is to use a regular expression to replace invalid characters with something else (e.g. as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590860/replacing-multiple-invalid-characters-in-a-sheet-name/8591088#8591088)).

Answer (score 0):

> date is dd/mm/yyyy it wont import it. I'M trying to get it to display it as 11th August 2011

Try the following

```
Option Explicit
Sub ChangeSheetName()
    Dim newname As String
    newname = Format(Range("D2"), "dd mmmm yyyy;@") ' 11 August 2011
    'or
    'newname = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2"), "dd mmmm yyyy;@") ' 11 August 2011
    ActiveSheet.Name = newname
End Sub
```

You don't have to format the cell, See Date [formats](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php)